# Reinstalling Windows 10 on upgraded PC after free upgrade period has ended

Tags: windows-10

If I ever need to reinstall Windows 10 on my upgraded Windows 8 laptop (have no product key because it's an OEM installation), will I still be able to? Does MS remember that I had it upgraded during the free upgrade period? Or will I be required to purchase a copy of Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you upgraded to Windows 10 during the free period and then rolled  back, it remembers that you once had Windows 10 and will allow you to re-install it.

Then you can try using the MediaCreationTool for Windows 10 from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/

I've put Windows 10 on a few machines at work then rolled back to Win7/Win8.1 and then had to put Windows 10 back on them for a new user.